# Regular Expression: Include Text After (...) Group

Tags: python, regex

I am learning about regular expressions.  I need to match things in a parenthesis group followed by some pattern that I define.  When I try this with regular expressions (in Python), it only returns the part in parentheses that it matched, but not the pattern which follows it.  An example should clarify:

```
import re
s = "texttoignore_ABCABC12345_moretexttoignore"
re.findall("(ABC)+\d+", s)
```

When I speak of the parenthesis group, in the example above this is the "(ABC)+" part. What I intend is for it to look for one or more repetitions of the pattern in parentheses (in this case "ABC"), then the pattern after.

The problem is this: it does not return the pattern after.  (In this example, it would return 'ABC', but I would want 'ABCABC12345' or 'ABC12345' or better yet '12345')

How can you include the part after the parentheses in the return value?  Is this something about regular expressions or is it specific to this Python method?

Thanks!

John

Comment: You could alternatively use `re.search()`: `re.search(r"(ABC)+\d+", s).group()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" here is that rather specific behavior of `re.findall`

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
>       list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>       has more than one group.

There are a few options you have here. Either make your group non-capturing:

```
>>> re.findall("(?:ABC)+\d+", s)
['ABCABC12345']
```

or use `re.finditer`:

```
>>> [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer("(ABC)+\d+", s)]
['ABCABC12345']
```

If you only want to find the pattern once, then @Jkdc's approach from the comments works fine.

```
>>> re.search("(ABC)+\d+", s).group()
'ABCABC12345'
```